# Bash convert two Epoch times to remaining time

Tags: bash, epoch

I'm trying to convert two Epoch (Unix timestamp) dates to human readable date (time left)

```
AT=$(echo $RES | jq '.results[0].unixtime' | tr -d '"') # Returns unix time in JST.
NOW=$(TZ=":Asia/Tokyo" date +%s) # Returns current time in JST
DIFF=$(echo $AT-$NOW | bc)
```

As an example;

```
AT=1470038400
NOW=1470032871
DIFF=5529
```

How do I get the remaining time between the two in the following format: DAYd HOURh MINm SECs?

Comment: I'd probably use `awk` to do the difference and formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following

```
printf "%dd %dh %dm %ds\n" $(( DIFF / (3600 * 24) ))  $(( (DIFF / 3600 ) % 24)) $(( (DIFF / 60) % 60)) $((DIFF % 60))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, I did change it to set itself into a variable, but it works :)